# How can I permanently remove a web browser's SSL warning for HTTPS sites that fail to identify themselves correctly?

Tags: ssl, web

I'm using Firefox and Google Chrome under Ubuntu 10.04, and get these warnings:

[image: firefox]

[image: chrome]

I want to add the site's certificate to "somewhere", so that the browser doesn't show SSL cert errors when visiting that given site.

p.s.: a command-line solution would be the best.

Comment: What you want is to completely disable ssl features? Looks foolish, please explain your motivations in your question, if any.

Comment: sorry if i wasn't clear enough, I just want to add a site's certificate to "somewhere", so that the browser doesn't shows SSL cert error when visiting that given site.

Comment: You can press the "Confirm security exception" to disable it for that one cert. Disabling it everywhere defeats the purpose of SSL. A certificate means "someone I turst says you are who you say you are". If you accept bad certs globally you basically say "I belive everything you tell me". Just like with plain HTTP.

Comment: In theory, this message is telling you that someone has hijacked your Internet connection or replaced the site by a decoy. In practice, this message is telling you that the site you're visiting is misconfigured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that the **Permanently store this exception** checkbox in Firefox is disabled is because you're in private browsing mode, or your security settings in Firefox are set to never remember history.

Set it to remember history, reload the page then permanently store it. After this you can change back to never remember.

I don't know if Chrome has a way to do that though.

Answer (score 2):

#### Non command-line solution

In the "Add Security Exception" window that appear for a specific site, push "get certificate", check "permanently store this exception" and push "Confirm security exception".

Comment: As I attached a printscreen, I CAN'T check the box: "permanently store this exception".

Comment: Ah right, in your case the domain name provided in the certificate is wrong. I fear that most browsers will not provide a way to suppress the warning in that case.

Comment: I will try to put a self-signed cert to this domain then..okay

Answer (score 1):

Does the site in question have a root certificate that you can download?

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/SSL-Certificates-HOWTO/x175.html

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/SSL-Certificates-HOWTO/

Comment: ehh, how can I check that? can you pls tell me?

Comment: you would have to look on the website. i had the same problem with the website of my uni. all subsites created their own certificates but once you trust the root all derived are trusted too. They had an extra tutorial for this to help the non it-students. The file was called <domainname>.der (i think)

Comment: :\ I'm not sure i could find the root cert:\ but TY!